How to change variable's color in html file in VS Code? - Angular
I have this in html and ts component files:
enter image description here
enter image description here
This is my code,color variable has color not outstanding
I would like to have the variables: reservationForm.get('checkInDate')?.invalid same color as above
I expect the color variable to turn like this

This may be because the Angular Language Service Extension is not installed. You can install it here.

II have installed this extension, but it still doesn't work
